# check java websocket authentication after login to the application and before @OnOpen connection

Tags: websocket, weblogic, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I am implementing avax.websocket to update the count for message as below in my application.

I want to secure the websocket endpoint and I used the below in web.xml and weblogic.xml but it did not work.
After that I tried to use custom ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator, now I am able to connect after logged to my application. But the session is coming as null in request.

With authentication in web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>WebSocketPrj</display-name>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>simple web resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>TestUser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>Basic</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>TestUser</role-name>
  </security-role> 
</web-app>
```

**weblogc.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
  <security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>TestUser</role-name>
    <principal-name>TestUser</principal-name>
  </security-role-assignment>
  <container-descriptor></container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

without security-constraint in web.xml and without weblogic.xml

```
public class WebSocketConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator{
private static final String ORIGIN = "http://localhost:7001";

@Override
public boolean checkOrigin(String originHeaderValue) {
    return ORIGIN.equals(originHeaderValue);
}

@Override
public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
    HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) request.getHttpSession();
    super.modifyHandshake(config, request, response);
    if (httpSession == null) {
        httpSession = (HttpSession) request.getHttpSession();
    }

    if (httpSession == null) {
        return;
    }

    config.getUserProperties().put("httpSession", httpSession);

    httpSession = (HttpSession) request.getHttpSession();
}
```

}

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/messageCount", configurator = WebSocketConfigurator.class)
public class NotificationSocket {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationSocket.class);

```
private Session wsSession;
private HttpSession httpSession;

/**
 *
 * @param session
 */
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config){

}

/**
 *
 */
@OnClose
public void onClose(){
    // implementation not needed
}

/**
 *
 * @param session
 * @param throwable
 */
@OnError
public void error(Session session,Throwable throwable){
    // implementation not needed
}

/**
 *
 * @param user
 * @param session
 */
@OnMessage
public void handleMessage(final String user, final Session session) {
    synchronized (session) {
        int count = 10;

        session.getAsyncRemote().sendText("" + count);

    }
}
```

}

I have login page and after login in welcomauth.jsp I am calling the below websocket:
and below is my javascript client:

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7001/messageCount");
    webSocket.onopen=function(){
    webSocket.send('Message');
    }
```

I don't want to pass the user information from client side in modifyhandshake I want to get the logged in user session then validate if the user exist then open the connection else throw exception.(like throw new RuntimeException("Not authenticated"))

**I am calling websocket after login to the application**. Is there any way to check authentication before the websocket connection(i.e @OnOpen)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. We need to add one servlet filter and add the url pattern same as the websocket serverendpoint.

In Servlet filter add the authentication logic. So when ever the websocket url called it will hit the filter and validate the authentication.